# Loop output each time button is pressed

Tags: vb.net, loops

The following function adds 2 numbers together, then moves the total to val1 and allows the user to add more numbers.  I need to print the output of each calculation.  (Ex. 2+2=4 nextline 4+2=6)
Currently I have a label that prints the first calculation.  How can I make a loop that prints val1, val2, and the result each time that the sum button is pressed?

```
Sub sum(s As Object, E As EventArgs)
        val2.Text = txtinput.Text
        Dim result = CInt(val1.Text) + CInt(val2.Text)
        txtinput.Text = result
        Label1.Text = val1.Text & "+" & val2.Text & "=" & result
        val1.Text = result
        val2.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Label1` is the control where you want to display the previous calculations all you need to do is to change `Label1.Text = val1.Text & "+" & val2.Text & "=" & result` to `Label1.Text += vbNewLine & val1.Text & "+" & val2.Text & "=" & result` to concat the previous inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the `label` is handled by this `Control` *(ex. Form, Panel)* and you can use  [.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to get all value of the `Label.Text` and `.Sum`

```
Dim sum = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().Sum(Function(c) Int32.Parse(c.Text))
```